# Why is msgrcv() feeding garbage characters into the buffer?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc, message-queue

right now, I am currently trying to output the contents of buf.mtext so I can make sure take the correct input before moving on with my program. Everything seems to work fine, except one thing; msgrcv() puts garbage characters into the buffer, and the reciever process outputs garbage characters.

Here is my sender process:

```
int main (void)
{
   int  i;                 // loop counter
   int  status_01;         // result status
   int  msqid_01;          // message queue ID (#1)
   key_t msgkey_01;        // message-queue key (#1)

   unsigned int rand_num;
   float temp_rand;
   unsigned char eight_bit_num;

   unsigned char counter = 0;
   unsigned char even_counter = 0;
   unsigned char odd_counter = 0;

   srand(time(0));

   struct message {
        long mtype;
        char mtext[BUFFER_SIZE];
   } buf_01;

   msgkey_01 = MSG_key_01; // defined at top of file

   msqid_01 = msgget(msgkey_01, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)
   if ((msqid_01 <= -1) { exit(1); }

   /* wait for a key stroke at the keyboard ---- */
   eight_bit_num = getchar();

   buf_01.mtype = 1;

   /* send one eight-bit number, one at a time  ------------ */
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_REPEATS; i++)
   {
      temp_rand = ((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*255.0;
      rand_num = (int)temp_rand;
      eight_bit_num = (unsigned char)rand_num;

      if ((eight_bit_num % 2) == 0)
      {
         printf("Even number: %d\n", eight_bit_num);
         even_counter = even_counter + eight_bit_num;
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Odd number:       %d\n", eight_bit_num);
         odd_counter = odd_counter + eight_bit_num;
      }

      /* update the counters ------------------------------ */
      counter = counter + eight_bit_num;
      if((eight_bit_num % 2) == 0) { even_counter = even_counter + eight_bit_num; }
      else { odd_counter = odd_counter + eight_bit_num; }

      buf_01.mtext[0] = eight_bit_num;   // copy the 8-bit number
      buf_01.mtext[1] = '\0';            // null-terminate it

      status_01 = msgsnd(msqid_01, (struct msgbuf *)&buf_01, sizeof(buf_01.mtext), 0);
      status_01 = msgctl(msqid_01, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}
```

Here is my receiver process:

```
int main() {

    struct message {
        long mtype;
        char mtext[BUFFER_SIZE];
    } buf;

    int msqid;

    key_t msgkey;

    msgkey = MSG_key_01;

    msqid = msgget(msgkey, 0666); // connect to message queue
    if (msqid < 0) {
        printf("Failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Connected\n");
    }

    if (msgrcv(msqid, &buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 0) < 0) { // read message into buf
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Data received is: %s \n", buf.mtext);
    printf("Done receiving messages.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output is usually something like as follows:

```
Data received is: ▒
Done receiving messages.
```

I have made sure to clear my message queues each time after running the sender and receiver processes, as well, since I have come to find out this can cause issues. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You're sending a random number to the receiver and hoping that number represents a valid printable character?

Comment: You're also not using the proper size of the structure you're sending, but the size of one of its members...

Comment: Like Shawn said... it's receiving garbage characters because you are sending garbage characters. It's working. You're receiving what you are sending. I don't know what you were *expecting* to receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out neither of the suggested solutions were the issue, as I suspected; the sender process actually works just fine. The problem was that I was trying to print buf.mtext instead of buf.mtext[0] which isn't an actual integer value. I fixed the issue by just doing this:

```
int temp_num = buf.mtext[0];
printf("Data recieved is %d \n", temp_num);
```